# Find row with certain value in column and move it to top of dataframe

Tags: r

I have the dataframe below and I would like to move the row with `C` in column `Reg` as 1st row.

```
Reg <- rep(LETTERS[1:3], each = 1)
Res <- c("Urban", "Rural","Urban")

df <- data.frame(Reg, Res)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple way is to create a logical vector on 'Reg' where the logical operator specified is `!=` (not equal to) returning all other values as TRUE and the row corresponding to 'C' as FALSE.  When we `order`, 'F' comes before 'T' in alphabetic ordering and thus 'C' rows will be the top followed by the rest

```
df[order(df$Reg != 'C'),]
```

---

Or similar options in `dplyr` are

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   slice(order(Reg != 'C'))
```

Or with `arrange`

```
df %>%
  arrange(Reg != 'C')
```

Comment: Brilliant answer with `!=`

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option

```
> df[order(replace(seq(nrow(df)),df$Reg=="C",0)),]
  Reg   Res
3   C Urban
1   A Urban
2   B Rural
```